# How to re-initialize ag-grid in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

[First of all, I tried searching on stackoveflow as well as on aggrid member support forum.  Couldn't find any relevant matches, for my issue.  So posting it here]

I'm using ag-grid for enterprise (trail version) in angular2 component.  In my component, I have a select dropdown w/ list of items.  Up on selecting one I'm actually loading the component that has the ag-grid in it.  Now, the issue is that, up on selecting another option, the ag-grid is not initialised again. I'm getting undesired behaviour therefore.  Below is my sudo code.  If there is a better option, let me know. I;m hoping there should be a way to do this, perhaps, using lifecycle hooks.

// parent.component.ts

```
import..

@Component({
  selector: 'card',
  template: '
        ....
      <select [(ngModel)]="value" (change)="somethingToDo()">
      <option *ngFor="let f of foo" [value]="f.id">{{f.value}}</option>
      </select>
      .....

      <div *ngIf="value > 0">
      <my-grid-component  [optionValue]="value"></my-grid-component>
        </div>
      ....
      ...
      '
})
```

// my-grid.component.ts

```
import ..

@Component({
    selector: 'my-grid-component',
    template: '
    ....
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-fresh"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
            (modelUpdated)="onModelUpdated()"
            (selectionChanged)="onSelectRow($event)">
  </ag-grid-angular>
.....
'
})
export class MyGridComponent implements onInit, onChanges {
  gridOptions;
  optionValue;

  constructor() {
    gridOptions = {};
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    if(optionValue>0) {
      this.doSomething();
    }
  }

  doSomething() {
    // I have to initialise the grid with new data and coldef.
    this.gridOptions.enableFilter = true;
    this.gridOptions.enableFilter = true;
    this.gridOptions.enableSorting = true;
    this.gridOptions.animateRows = true;
    this.gridOptions.floatingFilter = true;
    this.gridOptions.rowSelection = 'multiple';
  ....
    this.gripOptions.api.setRowData( this.getDataForValue(this.optionValue));
    this.gripOptions.api.setColumnDefs( this.getColDefsForValue(this.optionValue));
  ....
  }

  getDataForValue(inputValue) {
    // Server call
  }

  getColDefsForValue(inputValue) {
    // Server call
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am seeing this exact problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Prassana I am having the exact situation. Please let me know how did you resolve this issue ?

Comment: Similar situation for me, I just hide and show the grid again via an ng-if.